# Doxygen: how to combine multiple html outputs from different folders

Tags: doxygen

I have one projects with multiple sub-folders, and each subfolder has doxyfile cfg and would generate html output separately. Each html output would have one index.html.

How can I display all the html output in one page?

```
  root +
     |-src+
     |    |-a
     |    |-b
     |    |-c
     |
     |-doc+
          |-a.dox
          |-main.dox
          |-main.md
          |-output+
                  |-a+
                  |  |-html
                  |-b+
                     |-html
                  |-c+
                     |-html
```

Comment: So you are calling doxygen (which version?) for separately each directory, why not call it in the root directory and set the appropriate `INPUT` and / or `RECURSIVE` also have a look at the tag file `GENERATE_TAGFILE` (see for possible settings https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html).

Comment: Thanks Alert. I am using 1.8.17. The reason why I didn't cal it at root directory is each sub-directory has different owners, and they will handle the separated doxyfile config. I followed the guideline on https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/external.html, but seems nothing was linked, except the mainpage: main.md. I saw the a.tag generated, but not sure how this should be connected to the final doxygen files.

Comment: The tag files are there for linking between the different objects (like functions, pages etc.) of the different projects. As I understand now every owner creates its own html files and you want to combine them into a way so you only have 1 main page. Probably you can do something with tag files and the `\ref` and `\subpage` commands`.